# Ruby on Rails index.html.erb not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Just starting in Rails and I'm trying to get my index.html.erb page to show when I enter my rails-backend sub-domain.

I've been following the instructions from [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) but have run into some trouble. Searching google and SO for an answer did not yield results, so here I am.

I ran `$ rails generate controller home index` in order to generate `index.html.erb`, and deleted `public/index.html` as well. I then went to the `routes.rb` file in the /`config` directory and added this line:

`root :to => 'home#index'`

I also removed this line:

`get "home/index"`

My index.html.erb in the `app/views/home/` directory looks like this:

```
<h1>Hello Rails, my best friend!</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
<br />
<p>Also word to your mother</p>
```

I ran `rake routes` in the terminal and got this output:

(in var/www/testapp)
root / home#index

When I try to go to my sub-domain I get the following page:

[image: Error]

I then tried uncommenting the `get "home/index"` line in routes.rb, but the same result showed up. Here is my home_controller.rb file, which I didn't touch but a) the guide didn't ask me to and b) looks normal compared to other controllers I've seen:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I couldn't find any questions with a similar situation on SO. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Did you restart the server before testing?

Comment: Looks like I am in production mode, which does require a server restart! This leads to two new questions: 1)How would I change this to development mode? and 2) How do I restart the server?

Comment: Why do you run passenger on localhost? What's wrong with simple Webrick?

Comment: I'm actually running this on my webspace. I realize now that dev mode is for your local machine while production is for your website (at least that makes sense). So if I'm trying to get hello world to work on my webpage, I will need to keep it in production mode right? Also, I found that doing rails s should do a server restart, but it just waits for me to do Crtl-C to shut it down, and during that window where it is "open in development mode" the index.html.erb still doesn't load. Is there a different command for restarting the server in production mode?

Comment: Passenger can reload your site. You just have to `touch tmp/restart.txt`.

Comment: That just creates an empty .txt file named restart right? Tried that it and dropped the empty txt.file in the /tmp directory, but I still get that same error page on my index.

Comment: Passenger should watch this file and reload your app every time you `touch` it. There might be some problem with your instance. If I were you, I'd try advice by @thinkswan.

Answer (score 0):

Your code all looks correct. I would recommend foregoing Passenger and use the Thin server instead. It handles both `http` and `https`.

It's as simple as this:

- Add the following line to your `Gemfile`: `gem 'thin'`
- Install the gem: `bundle`
- Start the server: `bundle exec thin start --ssl`

This way, you receive the benefits of the Mongrel parser and SSL without needing any custom Apache configuration.

Comment: Hmm I may do that. Are you saying that in Apache Passenger requires configuration to run by default?

Comment: I'm saying that it's more common to run Rails applications on the Thin server than on Apache. Almost every Rails app on Heroku is running on the Thin server. Switch them and see if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: No dice, I am running this on my actual server rather than my local machine, I think this won't work for that.

Comment: Ah, this is for production! I must have missed that. In that case, I encourage you to run your application on Heroku (they provide Thin *and* your app should just work). That way, you can leave the server administration up to them and focus on what you're good at: building things.

Comment: From my understanding production is for actual hosting, whereas development is for just testing things on your local machine... is this correct?

Comment: That's correct, yes. Generally, you have a **development** environment for local work, a **staging** environment for testing your code in an environment mimicking production, and a **production** environment where you deploy your live app.